# InfoPath Calculated Value

Tags: infopath

I have info path form with three text boxes (tb1, tb2, tb3) and have calculated value field with (tb1+tb2+tb3).

Eg: If 1,2,3 are entered then it shows 6 in the calculated value field.

My Requirement:

If calculated value field is between 1-4 then it should show Low

If calculated value field is between 5-10 then it should show Medium

If calculated value field is between 11-14 then it should show High.

Now I need to Show whether it is Low/Medium/High based on the calculated value field on the info path form. Can anyone please explain step by step how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

It is more correct to realize it with rules but it is a lot of typing so I made it with custom C# code.
In Infopath Designer 2010 create a form naming controls accordingly:

[image]

[image]

On ribbon click **Developer** tab click **Changed Event** button having chosen each of text boxes, verifying changes in the code in opened VSTA (Visual Studio Tools for Applications) upon each click.

Make changes according this code snippet:

```
using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;  
using System; 
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Xml;  
using System.Xml.XPath;  
using mshtml;  

namespace IP_Calculated_Value {

    public partial class FormCode
    {
        int iTextBox1, iTextBox2, iTextBox3;
        XPathNavigator calculatedNode, textBox1Node, textBox2Node, textBox3Node; 
        public void InternalStartup()
        {
            calculatedNode = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().
                 SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Calculated", NamespaceManager);
            calculatedNode.SetValue
                ("Enter integers into textboxes and click outside to see calculated value");

            textBox1Node = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().
                SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:TextBox1", NamespaceManager);
            textBox2Node=this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().
                SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:TextBox2", NamespaceManager);
            textBox3Node = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().
                SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:TextBox3", NamespaceManager);

            EventManager.XmlEvents["/my:myFields/my:TextBox1"].Changed += 
                new XmlChangedEventHandler(TextBox1_Changed);
            EventManager.XmlEvents["/my:myFields/my:TextBox3"].Changed += 
                new XmlChangedEventHandler(TextBox3_Changed);
            EventManager.XmlEvents["/my:myFields/my:TextBox2"].Changed += 
                new XmlChangedEventHandler(TextBox2_Changed);
        }
        public void TextBox1_Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e)
        {
            iTextBox1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1Node.Value);
            ShowCalculated();
        }
        public void TextBox2_Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e)
        {
            iTextBox2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2Node.Value);
            ShowCalculated();
        }
        public void TextBox3_Changed(object sender, XmlEventArgs e)
        {
            iTextBox3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3Node.Value);
            ShowCalculated();
        }
        public void ShowCalculated()
        {
            int sum = iTextBox1 + iTextBox2 + iTextBox3;
            calculatedNode.SetValue("Outside of permitted sum range");
            if (sum >= 1 && sum <= 4) calculatedNode.SetValue("Low");
            if (sum >= 5 && sum <= 10) calculatedNode.SetValue("Medium");
            if (sum >= 11 && sum < 14) calculatedNode.SetValue("High");
        }
    }   }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add 3 calculated fields with text low, medium and high. on each calculated field add a formatting rule. the formatting rule hides the calculted field if it's not a low/medium/high value.

Calculated Field A: Value = Low, rule: hide when calculatedValue > 4 or calculatedValue < 1
Calculated Field B: Value = Medium, rule: hide when calculatedValue < 5 or calculatedValue > 10
Calculated Field C: Value = High, rule: hide when calculatedValue < 11 or calculatedValue > 14

Hope i got it right. Maybe you have to set the calculatedfield with a rule too.
I think c#-code is not necessary here.